# The fr_FR.UTF-8 and C.UTF-8 locales are not available in the locale list therefore I cannot use them

Tags: locale

The `fr_FR.UTF-8` and `C.UTF-8` locales are not available in the locale list (given by `locale -a`) therefore I cannot use them.

Here is what I did to try and add them :

```bsh
$ sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8 fr_FR fr_FR.UTF-8 
Generating locales...
  en_US.ISO-8859-1... up-to-date
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
  fr_FR.ISO-8859-1... up-to-date
  fr_FR.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales 
Generating locales...
  en_AG.UTF-8... done
  en_AU.UTF-8... done
  en_BW.UTF-8... done
  en_CA.UTF-8... done
  en_DK.UTF-8... done
  en_GB.UTF-8... done
  en_HK.UTF-8... done
  en_IE.UTF-8... done
  en_IN.UTF-8... done
  en_NG.UTF-8... done
  en_NZ.UTF-8... done
  en_PH.UTF-8... done
  en_SG.UTF-8... done
  en_US.ISO-8859-1... up-to-date
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZA.UTF-8... done
  en_ZM.UTF-8... done
  en_ZW.UTF-8... done
  fr_BE.UTF-8... done
  fr_CA.UTF-8... done
  fr_CH.UTF-8... done
  fr_FR.ISO-8859-1... up-to-date
  fr_FR.UTF-8... up-to-date
  fr_LU.UTF-8... done
Generation complete.
$ export LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8
$ export LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8
$ export LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8
$ locale -a
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
POSIX
en_US.utf8
```

EDIT 1 : On my system, `locale-gen` CAN take arguments because it's a bit old (package locales v2.13).

Anyway, the other method involving `/etc/locale.gen` doesn't work either :

```bsh
$ cat <<-EOF | sudo tee -a /etc/locale.gen
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_US ISO-8859-1
en_US.ISO-8859-15 ISO-8859-15
fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8
fr_FR ISO-8859-1
fr_FR@euro ISO-8859-15
EOF
en_US.UTF-8 UTF-8
en_US ISO-8859-1
en_US.ISO-8859-15 ISO-8859-15
fr_FR.UTF-8 UTF-8
fr_FR ISO-8859-1
fr_FR@euro ISO-8859-15
$ sudo locale-gen
Generating locales...
  en_AG.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_AU.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_BW.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_CA.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_DK.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_GB.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_HK.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_IE.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_IN.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_NG.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_NZ.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_PH.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_SG.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_US.ISO-8859-1... up-to-date
  en_US.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZA.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZM.UTF-8... up-to-date
  en_ZW.UTF-8... up-to-date
  fr_BE.UTF-8... up-to-date
  fr_CA.UTF-8... up-to-date
  fr_CH.UTF-8... up-to-date
  fr_FR.ISO-8859-1... up-to-date
  fr_FR.UTF-8... up-to-date
  fr_LU.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
$ locale -a
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
POSIX
en_US.utf8
```

The `fr_FR.UTF-8` and `C.UTF-8` locales are still NOT available in the locale list given by `locale -a`.

How can I do it?

Comment: do you have `localectl` installed on your system?

Comment: @Mioriin Yes, `localectl` is installed.

Comment: You use `localectl` to set locale. See `man localectl` for syntax info.

Comment: @Mioriin `localectl set-locale LC_MESSAGES=fr_FR.UTF-8` is asking me for my password just like the way `gksudo` would. Please understand I don't want to change the system's variables but only my variables.

Comment: What distribution do you have?

Comment: @Gilles I'm using Ubuntu Trusty :)

Comment: The file would be `/etc/locale.gen`, not `/etc/locale-gen`. But this file isn't used on trusty.

Comment: @Gilles Just renamed `/etc/locale-gen` to `/etc/locale.gen` and rerun `sudo locale-gen` but nothing changed

Comment: Your `fr_FR.ISO-8859-1` should really be `fr_FR.ISO-8859-15`. `-15` added Euro support to `-1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please guys, don't be mad at me :)

I finally found out why, something was wrong with my $PATH :

```bash
$ ssh localhost locale -a >/dev/null
$ which -a locale
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/locale
/usr/bin/locale
$ /home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/locale -a >/dev/null 
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
/home/linuxbrew/.linuxbrew/bin/locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
$ /usr/bin/locale -a >/dev/null
$ /usr/bin/locale -a | egrep -i "(C|fr_FR|en_US).utf-?8"
C.UTF-8
en_US.utf8
fr_FR.utf8
```

Answer (score 2):

`locale-gen` does not take any command-line arguments. Instead, it reads `/etc/locale.gen` for a list of locales to generate.

Edit `/etc/locale.gen` to uncomment the locales you want, and then run `locale-gen` again.

Or if there are no commented-out lines in `/etc/locale.gen`, find a list of supported locales and copy from there; in Debian (and probably related distributions), you can find such a list at `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`.

Comment: This depends on the distribution. Debian and Ubuntu's `locale-gen` have different syntax.

Comment: @Gilles Actually, Ubuntu Xenial has the same syntax as on Debian. The thing is I'm using Ubuntu Trusty :) Therefore I think the syntax of `locale-gen` has changed over time.